# How to Hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, swap, hibernate

It seems like Hibernate function is not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried with several commands like `sudo pm-hibernate`, and `sudo systemctl hibernate` etc. Nothing works.

Is hibernate also related to Hardware? My laptop RAM is 16GB and I have created the swap partition with the size of 24GB.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't work with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: Thanks, @Pilot6, it's a great help.